# Preloader gif have white pixels on edges

Tags: magento2.3

When I insert GIF into pre-loader - there are white pixels on edges.

```
                <img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/CustomLoader-1.gif')?>" alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                 echo __('Loading...');?>" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
```

Preloader downloaded from [loading.io](http://loading.io)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just use css preloader:

```
<div class="loader-overlay">
   <div class="lds-dual-ring"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.loader:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  z-index: 101;
}
.lds-dual-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 102;
}
.lds-dual-ring:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-color: #d3011b transparent #004396 transparent;
  animation: lds-dual-ring 1.2s linear infinite;
  z-index: 10;
}
@keyframes lds-dual-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```